# Find the asymptotic bound for the recurrence relation: $T(n) = T(\sqrt{n}) + 5n$

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

I've tried to expand the recursion:

$$T(n) = T(n^{\frac{1}{2}}) + 5n = T(n^{\frac{1}{4}}) + 5(n^{\frac{1}{2}} + n) = T(n^{\frac{1}{8}}) + 5(n^{\frac{1}{4}} + n^{\frac{1}{2}} + n)$$

We have a total of $\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor + 1$ elements in the recursion. So we can easily find an upper bound:
$$T(n) = O(n\cdot \log_2(n))$$

The thing is, I'm not sure it's a tight upper bound. More over, I haven't been able to reach a tight lower bound from the recursion. I've tried to, but I didn't get to the same assymptotic bound I've found above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: These T(n) = T(sqrt(n)) + ... questions are really coming into fashion, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the square root of $n$ halves the number of bits, so you indeed halve that number $\lg n$ times before the iterated square root falls below some predefined constant (say $4$).

Now we can write

$$n+\sqrt n+\sqrt[4]n+\sqrt[8]n+\cdots<n+\sqrt n+\sqrt n+\sqrt n+\cdots=n+\sqrt n\lg n,$$ which is $O(n)$.

---

**Justification:**

With $n=m^2$, $$\sqrt n\lg n\le n$$

becomes
$$2m\lg m\le m^2$$
or
$$2\lg m\le m,$$

which is true as of $m=4$.

Comment: Great answer. For the lower bound, is it safe to claim that $T(n) \ge 5n \ge n$, so $T(n) = \Omega(n)$, and in total we get $T(n) = \Theta(n)$?

Comment: @Yoxbox: yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use induction to show that $T(n) = O(n)$.

More concretely, try to prove using induction that you can find a $c\in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>n_0$, it will hold that $T(n) < cn$.

Basically, substituting this in the induction will reduce your recurrent formula into a simple equation that you will need to solve to find the suitable constants $c$ and $n_0$.

---

**Hint:** try picking $n_0>4$

Comment: Or try a really big n, like n = 2^1024 (over 300 decimal digits).

Answer (score 0):

Dropping the factor $5$ and reducing by $S(n):=\dfrac{T(n)}{5n}$, and with $S(10)=0$ (arbitrarily):

$$S(100)=\frac{S(10)}{10}+1=1$$
$$S(10000)=\frac{S(100)}{100}+1=1.01$$
$$S(100000000)=\frac{S(10000)}{10000}+1=1.000101$$
$$S(10000000000000000)=\frac{S(100000000)}{100000000}+1=1.00000001000101$$

It is clear that $S(n)$ gets closer and closer to $1$.

$$1<S(n)<(1+\epsilon)$$ where $\epsilon$ is a constant as small as you want, and $n>n_0$, giving

$$5n<T(n)<5(1+\epsilon)n.$$

Answer (score 0):

We want to find, $T(n) = T(\sqrt{n}) + 5n$

Assume $T(\epsilon) = c > 1$, $\epsilon > 1$ .

So $T(n) = T(\epsilon^{2k}) \\
= c + 5(\epsilon^2 +  \epsilon^4 + \cdots + \epsilon^{2k}) \\
< c + 5((k-1)\epsilon^{2(k-1)} + \epsilon^{2k})\\ = c + 5 (o(\epsilon^{2k}) +  \epsilon^{2k}) = O(5n)$

Comment: @gnasher729 here you can try $2^{1024}$. Just play with the exponent, and leave $2$ for this moment. You will add some numbers with $1024$ bit and all other things to be added can be summed up to $600$ bit at most.

Comment: If with $5n$ you mean "asymptotically no greater than $5n$", you are wrong.

Comment: @Yves Why? Where is the problem?

Comment: It is always greater than $5n$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

$$
T\left(2^{\log_2 n}\right) = T\left(2^{\frac 12\log_2 n}\right)+5n
$$

or recasting

$$
R(z) = R\left(\frac z2\right)+5\cdot 2^z
$$

and recasting again

$$
C(m) = C(m-1) + 5\cdot 2^{2^m}
$$

and after solving, backwards...